# Lubuntu - Start program without using terminal

Tags: wine, launcher, lubuntu, unity-dash

I just installed Lubuntu 12.04 on a Laptop. It is for my father and has to be user friendly. So I need a way to start programs graphically like by the "start button" equivalent to windows. The default programs are listed in the start menu, but I just installed wine and cannot find it in the menu. Where can I find programs that are not listed without using the terminal? Is there an equivalent to the ubuntu dash?

Comment: you can create a bash script and make it executable to open wine and put it on desktop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I installed Lubuntu 12.04 yesterday, and I just installed wine using `sudo apt-get install wine`, and once done I was able to find it on the Lubuntu menu.  See image below.

[image]

Comment: Seems that I did something wrong. I tried again, now it is there.

Answer (score 0):

To answer "*Where can I find programs that are not listed without using the terminal? Is there an equivalent to the ubuntu dash?*":

A normal Lubuntu installation has the "run" feature available by pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>. This gives you a small window to type what you want to run.

[image: Run dialog]

As you type, a drop down appears with auto-complete suggestions.

I would think that that is a low-fat "Dash" with the difference that this method only provides auto-completion whereas the suggestions in Ubuntu's "Dash" aren't purely auto-complete but also suggest applications based, *I guess*, on the `Name` entries in `.desktop` files.

Writing from memory, starting to type "text editor" in the Dash would quickly suggest `gedit`. Doing the same in Lubuntu's "Run" window gives you nothing even though there is a text editor, Leafpad, installed by default. In other words, Lubuntu's "Run" responds to **exact** strings included in the actual executable's name, the name you'd enter in a terminal (ignoring aliases). Also, note that the string we enter needs to start from the beginning. On my system, `gal` gives me `galculator` as the only match whereas `alculator` returns nothing.

[image: Run dropdown]

Answer (score 0):

I have installed Lubuntu and Wine in it serveral times. From my expirence there are no two Lubuntu installs that are exactly same. For Wine in particular, it sometimes shows up in menu, sometimes not, sometimes it only shows after two or three restarts. However, you do not really that Wine menu. Right-click on Windows exes, always contains an option to lauch via Wine.