# How to quickly open an application in Lubuntu?

Tags: lubuntu

I just switched from Ubuntu, where I can hit the <kbd>Super</kbd> key and search for any application I want and just hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>. In Lubuntu there doesn't seem to be a convenient way to quickly open an app in such manner?

Comment: See the answers here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/344820/lubuntu-start-program-without-using-terminal/344938#344938. You can also edit `~/.config/openbox/lubuntu-rc.xml` to set up convenient keybinds. For example, I have `Super`+`F` to open Firefox and `Super`+`C` to open Google Chrome. Read http://pclosmag.com/html/Issues/201107/page08.html to know more.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You have 3 options, **Synapse**, **Kupfer** or **GNOME Do**.

Synapse is a graphical launcher enabling you to start applications and also
to quickly find and access relevant documents and files (by making use of the
Zeitgeist engine).

```
sudo apt-get install synapse
```

[image]

Kupfer is a summoner/launcher in the style of Quicksilver or GNOME Do. It
can search and browse your files, launch desired applications and object
you need in a quicker way.

```
sudo apt-get install kupfer
```

[image]

Gnome Do Allows you to quickly search for many items present in your
GNOME desktop environment (applications, Firefox bookmarks, files,
artists and albums in Rhythmbox, Pidgin buddies,  etc.) and perform
commonly used actions on those items (Run, Open, Email, Chat, Play, etc.).

Although GNOME Do primarily targets the GNOME desktop, it also works
under other desktop environments.

```
sudo apt-get install gnome-do
```

[image]

You may find synapse more eyecandy, kupfer is the one that needs less dependencies if that worries you. Gnome Do has also a plugin to be used as dock (not enabled by default) but needs hardware acceleration for it.

All three use or adapt to your current gtk theme so they all look fine.

Comment: Chosen as answer since this is closest to Unity's Dash!

Answer (score 9):

Press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>, It shows the run dialog which is a good way to launch applications quickly.

You can change this keybard shortcut by editing `~/.config/openbox/lubuntu-rc.xml`.

Answer (score 1):

On Lubuntu 19.10 you can try:

- Go to menu and find the search bar on the bottom. Type  **shortcut keys** and hit enter. Then add
  the keyboard setting for the item with **show/hide runner** (number
  26 in this version.)

Then this bar shows up when you type the shortcut:[image: gif]

**Comment**: I set that up under <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd>, otherwise fast-resizing of windows with <kbd>super</kbd>+<kbd>left</kbd>/<kbd>super</kbd>+<kbd>right</kbd> doesn't work. But this is just an user option.