# Is there a way to see recent and pinned files like in Windows?

Tags: 16.04, launcher, directory

I'm using GNOME.

In Windows, you can right-click on applications in the taskbar to see your most recently used files, and files you've chosen to stay in the dock. This is one of my most missed features since switching

Here's an example:

[image: pinned folders in Windows]

Is there a way to have this feature in Ubuntu?

Comment: Technically this isn't 100% a duplicate because the user is also asking about the possibility of pinning directories/files. As far as "pinning" goes, there are ways to bookmark directories within a file manager; when you open a file manager window you can see bookmarked folders in the lefthand sidebar. I don't use Nautilus (Nautilus is the default file manager for Ubuntu) but I am pretty sure it has this feature. as for getting pinned things to show up when you press the Super button, for example, I'm not sure...

Comment: See these answers for more in depth info: https://askubuntu.com/questions/126446/how-can-you-access-a-folder-you-want-quickly

Comment: You also might like to look into these options: https://askubuntu.com/questions/379677/how-to-quickly-open-an-application-in-lubuntu

Comment: For pinned files AND recent files together in one place, see https://askubuntu.com/a/851339/295286 I've an indicator which offers that  feature